# Close current tab firefox using terminal

Tags: command-line, firefox

I have firefox already running on my system, and now in minimised state. What I want is to close the current tab running in firefox. How can I do this by simply using commands in terminal?

Comment: Referring to this: http://superuser.com/questions/191865/does-firefox-create-a-new-thread-per-tab-thread-per-instance, it may be difficult if not impossible to close tabs from a terminal.

Answer (score 6):

To keep `Firefox` minimized after closing its current tab (according to OP, see the [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/295584/close-current-tab-firefox-using-terminal/421316?noredirect=1#comment544281_421316)) use the following commands in a terminal,

```bsh
wmctrl -a firefox; xdotool key Ctrl+w; wmctrl -r firefox -b add,shaded
```

**How it works**

> **`wmctrl -a firefox`**
>
> Go to the window with a name containing 'firefox' in it
>
> **`xdotool key Ctrl+w`**
>
> Send the keystroke <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> to firefox which is the shortcut to close current tab in firefox.
>
> **`wmctrl -r firefox -b add,shaded`**
>
> Shade a window with a title that contains the word 'firefox' in it.

To know more about these see [`man xdotool`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/xdotool.1.html) and [`man wmctrl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/wmctrl.1.html)

**Alias for above command**

You can make an alias for the above commands, say the alias name be `cfct` ( Close Firefox Current Tab) in `~/.bashrc` or better in `~/.bash_aliases` from a terminal as,

```bsh
echo -e "\nalias cfct='wmctrl -a firefox; xdotool key Ctrl+w; wmctrl -r firefox -b add,shaded'" >> ~/.bash_aliases
. ~/.bash_aliases
```

If you don't have `~/.bash_aliases` replace `~/.bash_aliases` in the above commands with `~/.bashrc`

**Usage**

open a terminal and enter

```
cfct
```

And it will close Firefox’s current tab instantaneously.

**Note:** You need to have `wmctrl` and `xdotool` installed in your system. To install them use,

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl xdotool
```

Comment: the browser window gets opened, which is not supposed to. how to avoid this?

Comment: Quite unreliable in that it sends Ctrl+W to the last opened window, regardless if it is Firefox or not.

Comment: @minerz029 You are correct. check my edits.

Comment: Can i choose another tab than the current?

Comment: @m3nda You can switch tabs before you close the tab. You can switch to the first tab using Alt+1 or use any other number to switch to a different th tab. To close the 2nd tab for example: `wmctrl -a firefox; xdotool key Alt+2; xdotool key Ctrl+w; wmctrl -r firefox -b add,shaded`

Answer (score 2):

You can install this Add-on: https://github.com/bard/mozrepl/wiki and enable it with Tools->MozRepl->Start. After that you can script Firefox from outside. Create following test.js file:

```
window.getBrowser().removeCurrentTab()
repl.quit()
```

And run it following way:

```
nc localhost 4242 < test.js
```

Answer (score -3):

Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

`xkill`

and click on the tab you want to close.

Comment: firefox is minimised, i have already stated.

Comment: Also: `xkill` would kill the whole Firefox and not only one tab.