# How can I make a shortcut to raise an application's window if it exists?

Tags: shortcut-keys, window-manager, wmctrl

I constantly switch between Sublime Text, Terminal and Chrome. I'd like to bind shortcut like "Alt + 1" so my current Terminal and current Google Chrome opens.

Right now, each time i launch Google Chrome or the terminal, it opens a new window. Any idea ?

Thanks !

Comment: Posted an alternative, doing exactly as you say. Please mention if anything is unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method in drizzle's answer will work, but has a few downsides

- It has a delay; when pushing the <kbd>Super</kbd> key, you'd have to wait about a second to make the numbers appear.
- The order of the items in the launcher might be changing, depending on the applications you run. The number of `Chrome` might be different then.

  [image]

#### Alternative option

You *could* simply do with the command:

```
wmctrl -a chrome
```

which will raise the first found window with "chrome" in its name. That would however also raise the window I am writing in now (`a firefox` window, named: *"Shortcut to open current Google Chrome..."*)

The use of the window's pid will prevent this. In my opinion, it is therefore more elegant to put the command:

```
wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep chrome)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

under a shortcut key (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd> will work), given the fact that you'd need to have `wmctrl` installed then:

```
sudo apt-get install wmctrl
```

#### How to add the command to a shortcut

1. Install `wmctrl`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install wmctrl
   ```
2. create a small script (open an empty file, paste the script below in it)

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep chrome)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
   ```

   Save it as `raise_chrome.sh`
3. Add the script to a shortcut; choose: System Settings > "Keyboard" > "Shortcuts" > "Custom Shortcuts". Click the "+" and add the command:

   ```
   /bin/bash /path/to/raise_chrome.sh
   ```

   to (e.g.) the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>.

   **N.B.** Use an absolute path, not e.g. `~`

#### Explanation

The command is in fact a "conversion" of [this one](https://askubuntu.com/a/616767/72216), and the explanation is similar:

In the section:

```
"$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep chrome)" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

the command:

```
wmctrl -lp
```

lists all windows, including their pid and window- id. The result is piped to

```
grep "$(pgrep chrome)"
```

which filters (lists) all occurrences of `Chrome` windows.

Then,

```
tail -1
```

will give us the last item in the list, which is the latest created window (since `wmctrl` lists windows chronologically).

```
awk '{ print $1 }'
```

finally, will give us the first string in the line (from the output of `wmctrl`), which is the window- id.

The command:

```
wmctrl -ia <window_id>
```

Will then raise the *last created* window of `Chrome`

#### Note

No need to say that you can replace `chrome` in the command by any other application (process name), and place them under separate key combinations.

---

### EDIT

#### use the application as an argument

Since you mention  `Sublime Text`, `Terminal` and `Chrome`, you might want to use multiple shortcuts, and run the script with the application as an argument.

#### To do so

Use the script with slight difference:

```
#!/bin/bash
app=$1
wmctrl -ia "$(wmctrl -lp | grep "$(pgrep "$app")" | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1 }')"
```

and run it subsequently with the commands under the shortcut keys:

```
sh /home/jacob/Bureaublad/raise.sh sublime_text
sh /home/jacob/Bureaublad/raise.sh gnome-terminal
```

and

```
sh /home/jacob/Bureaublad/raise.sh chrome
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use alt-tab to switch quickly between the programs.

You can also use the Super button (aka Windows button) like this: Super+number. eg. Super+3 will open the third app in your app launcher. To quickly identify the numbers associated with the apps, press and hold the super button.

Comment: I find switching between programs with Alt + Tab a bit exhausting, I'm mainly using Chrome, Terminal and Sublime Text. Shortcut for each program would realy be quicker ! 
Furthermore, my two screens make it even more confusing, you're not always sure to have the focus.