# How can I make wmctrl raise the most recently fosused window of an application?

Tags: scripts, window, window-manager, wmctrl

I have a script running `wmctrl -x -a "$1"`. It brings up the window, passed as the argument to the script e.g.:

```
wmctrl -x -a "Firefox"
```

activates firefox.

However, with applications that have multiple windows, it doesn't bring up the *last* used windows. Consider I have 3 windows open in `LibreOffice Writer`, named 'Doc 1', 'Doc 2' and 'Doc 3' and I am on Doc 3 and I move to another application. Executing the script brings up 'Doc 1' and not 'Doc 3' which was last used.

Any flag to fix this problem in `wmctrl`?

Comment: There is currently no existing way to get the focus history, although it is recorded inside Unity. It *can* be retrieved by a background script though. If that is an acceptable solution for you, I will split off such a solution from this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/745813/72216, just let me know.

Comment: What about Alt+Tab?

Comment: @JacobVlijm would be happy to see the "split off" solution.

Comment: @EyalLevin posted :)

Answer (score 2):

On request, a splitoff of another answer, supplemented with a new section.

#### Focus history of windows

*How to raise the most recently focused window of an application*

As mentioned in my comment, currently, there is no focus history of windows. That means that if we need it, we need to create it ourselves. The first script below exactly does that; It keeps track of the currently focused window, and stores the history in a tiny file, refreshed once per second.
The order of the lines is also the order of focus; the top line represents the latest focused window, the last line the "oldest".

To make a script raise the most recently focused window of an application, all we need to do is to read the lines from top to bottom, find the first occurrence of a window of the application, and raise it. That is exactly what the second script does, if you run it with the `WM_CLASS` of the sought window.

#### The scripts

1. The background script, keeping track on focus history. This script is an exact copy of the first one [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/745813/72216):

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import subprocess
   import time
   import os

   rootdata = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.focus_history"
   open(rootdata, "wt").write("This is an empty line")

   def current_windows():
       try:
           return subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-lp"]).decode("utf-8")
       except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
           pass

   def convert_format(w_id):
       return w_id[:2]+(10-len(w_id))*"0"+w_id[2:]

   def read_data():
       return open(rootdata).read().splitlines()

   def get_top(wlist):
       try:
           top = convert_format(
               [l.split("#")[-1].strip() for l in subprocess.check_output(
                   ["xprop", "-root"]
                   ).decode("utf-8").splitlines() \
                  if "_NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW(WINDOW)" in l][0])
           return [l for l in wlist if top in l][0]
       except IndexError:
           pass

   if __name__ == "__main__":
       while True:
           time.sleep(1)
           wdata = current_windows()
           if wdata != None:
               wlist = wdata.splitlines()
               # get frontmost window (as in wmctrl -lG)
               top = get_top(wlist)
               oldlist = read_data()
               if not any([top == oldlist[0], top == None]):
                   # clean up closed windows
                   [oldlist.remove(l) for l in oldlist if not l.split()[0] in wdata]
                   # remove possible other mentions of the active window
                   [oldlist.remove(l) for l in oldlist if l.startswith(top.split()[0])]
                   open(rootdata, "wt").write(("\n").join([top]+oldlist))
   ```

   Copy the script into an empty file, save it as `focus_history.py`
2. The script to raise the latest focused window of an application.

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python3
   import os
   import subprocess
   import sys

   lookfor = sys.argv[1]
   winhistory = os.environ["HOME"]+"/.focus_history"

   for l in open(winhistory):
       wid = l.split()[0]
       wmclass = subprocess.check_output(
           ["xprop", "-id", wid, "WM_CLASS"]
           ).decode("utf-8").strip()
       if lookfor in wmclass:
           subprocess.check_output(["wmctrl", "-ia", wid])
           break
   ```

   Save it as `raise_recent.py`.

#### How to use

1. make sure `wmctrl` is installed:

   ```
   sudo apt install wmctrl
   ```
2. Test- run the first script as a backgrounder with the command:

   ```
   python3 /path/to/focus_history.py
   ```

   ***N.B*** make sure the script starts *before* other windows open, else the windows will only be recorded (of course) once they get their first focus.
3. Call the second script with the command (e.g.)

   ```
   python3 /path/to/raise_recent.py gedit
   ```

   ...to raise most recently focussed window of `gedit`.
4. If all works fine, add the first script to Startup Applications. Note however you probably need to add a break before the script to start, to prevent `wmctrl` to break. (Although the script shouldn't, since it handles the possible exception).

That's it.