# How do I close a pdf from Ubuntu command line?

Tags: command-line, pdf, xdg-open

Suppose I open a file (pdf) with a command line in Ubuntu by running

```
xdg-open abc.pdf
```

The pdf is shown in a pdf reader which is set as default.

Now how can I close this pdf viewer from the command line in Ubuntu?

Comment: try `pkill <pdf_viewer_process_name>`

Comment: Just beware that this will close ALL pdfs opened with xdg-open - which is fine as long as that's your intent.

Comment: Not from command line, but you can press Alt+F4 to close a window (or sometimes Ctrl+Q or Ctrl+W). That might be more convenient in the end.

Comment: xdotool might be useful. Maybe you could use it to find which window has that PDF open, and close it.

Comment: An -almost- dupe of this one https://askubuntu.com/questions/616738/how-do-i-close-a-new-firefox-window-from-the-terminal  but you could of course get the window- id by just wmctrl, make your pick, then `wmctrl -ic <window_id>`

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> fuser -k -TERM FILE
> ```
>
> Replace `FILE` with the name of the file in question.

Check the link below for a fuller description (and be aware this is a powerful/ dangerous command)

Source: [Is there something like an “xdg-close” - opposite of xdg-open?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/396110/117037) on Unix & Linux